# Chain Slipping?

Tags: chain, derailleur, derailleur-rear

I am not the most knowledgeable when it comes to bikes so please bear with me. I have a Claud Butler and after fixing a puncture I decided to ride it. As I was riding, I could hear a sort of rattling whilst in the low gears, but then when I went up in gears, I noticed that the sound continued but also it felt like the chain was slipping. After inspecting it later, I believe it has something to do with the rear derailleur, as every now and then it would spring forward a little and then return to just the rattling sound.

What could be causing this problem, and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: what did you do when you fixed the puncture? did that coincide with the start of the problems?

Comment: I moved the derailleur so that I could get the wheel out and take the chain off

Comment: Did you actually take the chain off the bike? (You'd need a tool to do this.)

Comment: No, I mean I took the chain of the crank.

Comment: This can happen when you get a washer on the wrong side of the "dropout" slot or simply do not get the wheel properly seated in the slots.

Comment: I think I have found the problem. When looking at the chain, I notice that one of the chain links are not in line. I move this so that it is in line but it automatically moves back when going round

Comment: @Jordan, could you post an image please? That could just be a sticky link caused by a dirty chain, but it's possible the chain became damaged when you changed your tyre.

Comment: Or you could have bent the derailleur when moving it.

Comment: Rotate the chain to where the "stiff" link is on top, between the two sprockets.  Grasp it with your hands and try to bend it in the direction it doesn't want to bend (ie, sideways), first one way, then the opposite way.  Don't apply enough force to actually bend the chain, but put a little muscle on it.  This will often loosen a "stiff link".  If that doesn't do it the chain may need replacing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are describing, sounds like the chain is either trying to climb gears or drop gears.  This is caused by incorrect cable tension on your derailleur.

While riding the bike, watch (or to be safe, have someone else watch) your rear sprocket and see if the chain is trying to climb up to the next bigger gear, or drop down the the next smallest gear.  If either is the case, you can attempt to correct this yourself by making minor adjustments to the derailleur cable tension, then riding to test if the behavior is improving.

Use the derailleur adjustment barrel on the derailleur [see image] (or there is often one on the shiftier on the handlebar as well).  If the chain is trying to climb, loosen tension on the cable by turning the barrel clockwise, if dropping, increase tension by turning the barrel counter clockwise.  Make minor adjustments ( 1/8 to 1/4 turn at a time).

[image: derailleur adjustment barrell]

Since you are not that familiar with bicycles, you could mark where you start, so you can return to that point if this does not correct your issue.  The adjustment shouldn't require more than a couple full turns at best.